# M2.4.6 - Unable to extend Tier Pricing Template

Tags: magento2.4.6

I have created a module to extend the Tier Pricing template, but the getPrice() is not returning anything therefore the tier pricing array is always null

[image]

Any hint is appreciated.

Here is my layout XML:
custom_catalog_product_prices.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Custom_ExtendedTierPrice::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <!--<item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array"></item>-->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</layout>
```

- catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.render.default">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="price_render_handle" xsi:type="string">custom_catalog_product_prices</argument>
                <argument name="use_link_for_as_low_as" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                <!-- set "override" configuration settings here -->
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </body>
</layout>
```

- tier_prices.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>

<?php
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate
// phpcs:disable Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox $block */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\LocaleFormatter $localeFormatter*/
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice $tierPriceModel */
$tierPriceModel = $block->getPrice();
$tierPrices = $tierPriceModel->getTierPriceList();
$msrpShowOnGesture = $block->getPriceType('msrp_price')->isShowPriceOnGesture();
$product = $block->getSaleableItem();
?>
<?php if (count($tierPrices)) : ?>
    <h1>TEST</h1>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I hope it helps someone in a similar situation.

Summary: I missed the fact "Configurable products" with Tier Prices are not using the same template as "Simple products", in other words, my code is correct, all I had to do was to update the configurable argument; here is my updated custom handle XML:

[image]

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Custom_ExtendedTierPrice::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <!--<item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array"></item>-->
            </argument>
            <argument name="configurable" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\TierPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Custom_ExtendedTierPrice::product/price/configurable_tier_prices.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</layout>
```